# Why did the UK use hewn stone cubes for homes far more often than France?

Tags: technology, industrial-history, construction

Why did the UK use hewn stone cubes ([ashlar masonry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ashlar)) for homes far more often than France in the previous centuries?

It would be rare to find this kind of rustic stone ([rubble masonry](https://civilengineeringbible.com/article.php?i=135) ) in the UK, whereas 80% of old homes in Southern France are built like [this](https://www.google.com/maps/@45.2111416,4.6777616,3a,60y,304.54h,95.54t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1spl9WQc19lsKAHtBzOCp30Q!2e0!7i13312!8i6656).

In the UK even tough stones in remote villages are often hewn into [rectangles](https://www.google.com/maps/@52.3002607,-3.5099846,3a,75y,130.13h,89.92t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sPKxP3mh7wOW_1NBUJ0Cu5A!2e0!7i13312!8i6656).

Comment: It's a shame that none of the Geography SE proposals gaineed traction, since it would have fit perfectly.

Comment: Is this a fact, or just an impressionistic guess based on a limited range of samples?

Comment: In point of fact, none of your links show actual cubes of masonry being used.  They are rectangular blocks.

Comment: search  "english stone village house" give about 60% ashlar homes, the same search in french "maison française village pierre" gives 5% ashlar. 1/https://www.google.com/search?biw=1241&bih=646&tbm=isch&sxsrf=ACYBGNTiVRaQyE4R_Ru7jMMx4sTliWancg%3A1572201325747&sa=1&ei=beO1XdekLa-SlwSzyIDACA&q=villige+house+english+stone&oq=villige+house+english+stone&gs_l=img  ,,,   and ... 2/https://www.google.com/search?biw=1241&bih=646&tbm=isch&sxsrf=ACYBGNRtuMhqnieMdhwgy22499H21XISzw%3A1572201355849&sa=1&ei=i-O1Xa7HM8-AafGmhPAI&q=maison+village+française+pierre&oq=maison+village+française+pierre&gs_l=img

Comment: Speaking as an archaeologist, I would generally expect the materials used for vernacular architecture in the UK to reflect the materials available locally.  Where free-cutting limestone is available from local quarries, I am not surprised to see it used as a building material (simply sawn into conveniently sized blocks) as quoins or as the main building material.  Equally, I am not surprised to see 'wattle-and-daub' construction used alongside higher-status buildings that use ashlar masonry where both are available. I would be surprised if the situation were significantly different in France.

Comment: To give some further context, this article in Country Life magazine describes [10 types of cottage you’ll find in Britain](https://www.countrylife.co.uk/property/small-beautiful-10-types-cottage-youll-find-britain-180933).  Note that none of the 10 types mentioned use ashlar masonry.

Comment: I have lived 29 years in the UK and 12 years in southern half of France. If i search "stone cottage" i see 25% are from ashlar. 80-98% percent of stone homes in regions of Ardeche, Loire, Savoie, and south france are rough blocks on google images. For UK counties the rough stone homes are rarely above 50% for the same search.

Comment: isnt the question at odds with the title ? Title : "Why UK ...far *more often* than france" text: "Why did the UK use hewn stone cubes (ashlar masonry) for homes far more often than France in the previous centuries?

It would be *rare* to find this kind of rustic stone (rubble masonry ) *in the UK*, whereas 80% of old homes in Southern France are built like this. Shouldn't the title and first sentence say "UK _less_ often" ?

Comment: Read it again, No, more hewn stone in the UK whereas many areas of France have very few hewn rocks, including regions with limestone. i.e. image search "alpes maritimes maison pierre" Maritime Alps, limestone, nearly all the homes are rubble masonry:

Comment: I suspect this is regionally-specific. Rubble building is very common in Scotland, for instance. In other areas, brick has been the usual construction material for centuries, depending on the availability of suitable clay. I'm still not convinced on any difference where the only evidence is google image searches (which aside from other biases will give different results for everyone who searches based on their history).

Comment: Having travelled 50,000 kilometers through small roads in France, I have only seen a couple of villages where I thought "OMG!!! SOME CUT STONES... SOME CUT STONES!!!" They are nearly non existent. Yes, Building materials are regionally specific. No, Scotland doesn't have a scarcity of cut rock houses, in fact the towns there are often 50/50 of both types. Zoom in on google maps, even near Sterling and Dundee, the villages have vast numbers of cut rocks. Zoom into french villages of the same size nearly anywhere, stone cut houses are rare in most regions.

Comment: By the way, if you zoom to french towns to search for cut-rock houses, the houses are almost invariably covered in white plaster, with cut corner-stones and lintels. The houses are plastered over because they have rough masonry. Cut rock is very ornamental and weather-proof, and is rarely plastered over.